# Strange characters when copying URL of WordPress page

Tags: wordpress, url

URLs are fine when you view them in browser, but when you copy them they look like following:

```
http://draingoplumbing.com/bathroom%E2%80%8B-%E2%80%8Bplumbing%E2%80%8B-%E2%80%8Bmemphis%E2%80%8B-%E2%80%8Btn%E2%80%8B-%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8Bemergency%E2%80%8B-%E2%80%8Bplumber/
```

I have checked permalink structure option in WordPress and it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

The text string in your question is URL-encoded. You cna decode it here. https://urldecode.org/ Then hover over the decoded text, right click and hit Inspect...

Here's your situation. For some reason your permalinks have, rather than hyphens, the character sequence

```
 &#8203;  hyphen  &#8203;
```

in them.

`&#8203;` is the oddball Unicode typographic character called [zero-width space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm).  Its purpose is to allow line breaks between characters when necessary without also introducing space between them.

It seems likely there's an error in your permalinks. I guess your post has the slugs like this:

```
   bathroom plumbing / memphis tn / emergency
```

So whatever text you have in your permalinks for hyphens has those zero-width spaces before and after them.  Erase and retype your permalink templates in Settings / Permalinks.

Comment: This one is what we call vuja dé.  The opposite of déja vu. Never seen anything like it before. :-)